# Ubuntu 20.04 Mate: Cannot acces data from external harddrive

Tags: 20.04, permissions, hard-drive, ubuntu-mate

I try to find out, how I can copy data from my external drive on my new computer... Ubuntu is very eager telling my, that I don't have permission, lol (it's my drive and my data...) I can access it, navigate inside the folder structure inside and that's it. No copying, no deleting folders, nothing. Could anybody please explain my, what's going on here? I never had this problem  with any other computer before. But yeah, I never used linux before. So, seems I've to learn a lot...

I already tried:

> sudo chown -R $USER.$USER /media/mic/BACKUPDRIVE

but it didn't work...

**What can I do in order to get this easy job done?**

Any help would be awesome!

BR
Mic

Comment: is that exactly what you typed $USER.$USER? If not, please [edit] your question with exactly what you typed.

Comment: Ok, edited. Sorry, was a little typo here in the forum...

Comment: Ok, understand...

Comment: No, I got this:
chown: changing ownership of '/media/mic/BACKUPDRIVE': Read-only file system
Nothing changed...
Is this a problem with the filesystem on my external drive?

Answer (score 0):

If your user name is fred then the command is

sudo chown fred:fred /media......

add any options as required.

replace fred with your own username.

[man page chown](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html)

Comment: Terminal: sudo chown mic:mic /media/mic/BACKUPDRIVE --> Output: chown: changing ownership of '/media/mic/BACKUPDRIVE': Read-only file system
Nothing changed! What the hack does read-only-filesystem mean?